# Securing an Angular Application

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

We're looking to secure an Angular application that is running in an MVC project.

If I secure the MVC app using hybrid flow, then all the Angular $http calls are jQuery $.ajax calls under the hood.  Which if I remember rightly, sends all cookies with each web API call.

My question is, how should I secure this application.  Do I need to secure the MVC app using hybrid flow and then do I need to further secure the APIs?

EDIT

I've just been watching the NDC video and it talks about asking for 2 tokens when you originally authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between an angular app and MVC is usually secured using session cookies. If you need your APIs to be called from other apps then you better move those APIs to WEBAPI and communicate with them using bearer tokens. If you already have other APIs that require bearer token, you can get an access token in hybrid flow and talk to those APIs(from either the angular app or the MVC app).